# Compiling and deploying a custom Solr request handler

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I've written my own custom Solr search request handler. It's a single Java source file defining a single class. How do I compile the request handler and introduce it to my instance of Solr? I guess I'm supposed to create a JAR file out of the java source file and put that JAR somewhere so that Solr would be aware of the class. If that is indeed what I have to do, then how do I generate a JAR file out of a single Java source file without compiling the whole core of Solr? And after having the request handler JAR, where do I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) to create a jar.

Once the jar is created you need to put the jar in the `lib` directory in the `instanceDir` of your SolrCore. For more details have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins).

You need to add the following in your `solrconfig.xml` -

`<lib dir="../../../lib/yourjarname"/>`

Comment: I put the jar file in under the `lib` directory and running the server resulted in a `Class Not Found Exception`. The handler class is named `RelevanceFeedbackHandler` and it's under the `org.apache.solr.handler` package. I've added the request handler section to the `solrconfig` file with `org.apache.handler.RelevanceFeedbackHandler` as the value of the `class` attribute. What's wrong with what I've done?

Comment: How does your requestHandler in the solrconfig.xml look like?

Comment: @JHS I'm having the same java.lang.ClassNotFoundException not found exception and was wondering how to fix it. I've compiled a jar with a single class file called UserUpdateHandler in a package com.bouncy. My solrconfig.xml then has the line <requestHandler name="/update" class="com.bouncy.UserUpdateHandler">.

Comment: @nightscent - Have you included the jar file in the solrconfig.xml using the lib tag? The last line in my answer is the lib tag that you need to add in the solrconfig.xml.

Comment: @JHS Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried various <lib dir=".." /> combinations but still am unable to resolve the issue :( At the moment my jar is thrown in my coreDir/lib where all the jetty jars seem to be. So I'm currently using <lib dir="../../../lib" /> Is there anywhere to see where all the lib tags are resolving to?

Comment: @JHS Thanks! I think the jar is already being loaded because I can see [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader  – Adding 'file:/Users/Kevin/Development/solr-4.9.0/volaten/solr/users/lib/TestJar.jar' to classloader.